# split for words separated with semicolon

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have some string like

1;2;3;4;5

I want to be able to iterate over this string taking each word one by one. For the first iteration to take 1 the next to take 2 and the last 5.

I want to have something like this

```
for i in $(myVar)
do
echo $i
done
```

but I do not know how to fill the myvar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo '1;2;3;4;5' | tr \; \\n | while read line ; do echo $line; done
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to back up the IFS variable if you assign it only for a single command:

```
$ IFS=';' read -a words <<<"1;2;3;4;5"
$ for word in "${words[@]}"
do
    echo "$word"
done
1
2
3
4
5
```

Other useful syntax:

```
$ echo "${words[0]}"
1
$ echo "${words[@]: -1}"
5
$ echo "${words[@]}"
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is change the `IFS` environment variable:

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=';'
for num in $a; do echo $num; done

# prints:
1
2
3
4
5

IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Remember to change it back afterwards or weird things will happen! :)

From the bash man page:

```
   IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is  used  for  word  splitting
          after  expansion  and  to  split  lines into words with the read
          builtin  command.   The  default  value  is  ``<space><tab><new-
          line>''.
```

Comment: Or you could run in a sub-shell :) ... `(IFS=';'; for num in $a; do echo $num; done)`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
array=($(sed 'y/;/ /' <<<"1;2;3;4;5"))
for word in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$word"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for w in $(echo '1;2;3;4;5' | tr \; \\n); do echo $w; done
```